# DynamoDB NOT EQUALS on GSI sort key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

As the title suggest, I'm in a situation where I need to fetch all records from a dynamo table GSI, given that I know the hash key and I know the sort key that I want to avoid.

The table looks like this:

```
Id - Primary Key,
AId - GSI hash key,
BId - GSI sort key
```

I need an efficient query to get records by a query like this

`AId = 1 and BId != 2`.

DynamoDB doesn't support `<>` operator when querying on hash and sort keys, it's only present on filter expressions, but those are not allowed on any of the primary key fields either.

So what would be the solution here? Scanning is probably not a good idea, unless it would be possible to scan on a partition, but that doesn't seem to be supported either.

So the only solution that is obvious to me at this point is querying by the partition key and then filtering it out client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your sort key is actually numeric as shown in your example...

Then your best option would be to issue two separate queries..

`AId = 1 and BId < 2`

`AId = 1 and Bid > 2`

Actually, as I write this...I think it would work regardless of the type of sort key...

Comment: It's actually a string, I just wanted to give a simple example, but I'll give it a try tomorrow and get back to you.

Comment: Be careful while using `>` and `<` with strings.
In javascript `"20" > "101"` evaluates to `true`.

Comment: @AnkitDeshpande shouldn't matter as the OP is looking for !=

Comment: You can also use a filter expression to remove the one you don't want. If your records are small (probably <2k) this will be more efficient than two queries.